# SharePoint 2010 performance

Tags: performance, caching, sharepoint

I want to enhance the performance some Intranet site.
Every page access takes at least 6 seconds to complete.
Enabling Developer Dashboard, I notice that the same operation is conducted more than 10 times and the total lasts like 5s. This operation is "CachedObjectFactory: Caching Page at xxxx" or "Caching Web at xxx".
I thought it was related to our custom masterpage. Even using the v4.master, the behavior is the same.
The more the site collection contains subsites, the more it is slow.
I checked that the output cache is correctly enabled and configured on this site collection.
I also tried to backup/restore the site colleciton on a different content database...but no more luck here. So it's not related to a unhealthy SQL database.
I also set the superuser and superread accounts of the site collection to an account which has Full Control in the User Policy on the hosting web app. 
Still no change.

However, I installed the SP2 (SP1 was already installed). And hurray! 6s access times become 3s....STILL TOO SLOW...u_u'


Any new fresh idea is welcome !

screenshot here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/fzis3ofg158h64v/rpst3.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Just to clarify - the page has completely loaded in the browser in 3 seconds, and you want it to be faster than that - e.g. 2 seconds or 1 second?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65695/sharepoint-2013-extremely-slow

Comment: yes exactly, otherwise the user experience is bad

Comment: The mentionned duplicate is not one, because in this duplicate we talk about SP2013 and the Distributed Cache, which does not exist in SP2010.